# Exporting DBSCAN data in to a CSV

Tags: python, dbscan

I have clustered Iris data set with DBSCAN. Here is the code I have used

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\05807\Desktop\New folder (5)\FinalX.csv")
data = np.mat(data)

X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=150, cluster_std=0.4,
                            random_state=0)

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

db = DBSCAN(eps=0.3, min_samples=10).fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print('Estimated number of noise points: %d' % n_noise_)
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels))
print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

After running the above, it shows a clustering in a graphical way.

What I want is to export the result clusters in to a CSV . That means adding a new column infront of the data as new clustered field. Can anyone help me?

Comment: anyone care to help?

Comment: This is a very easy to solve problem, but you have too many lines code. You need to keep only the essential to understand your problem. Don't assume that everybody has time to understand all your code.  Read How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @jjsantoso Hi. yes . thats what i have mentioned at the bottom. All I want is to export the desired outcome to a CSV.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DBSCAN Clustering - Exporting the clustered outcome to a new column issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882879/dbscan-clustering-exporting-the-clustered-outcome-to-a-new-column-issue)