# DBSCAN Clustering - Exporting the clustered outcome to a new column issue

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I have made a code using python under Iris Data set - the clustering technique i used is DBSCAN. I need to take out the desired outcome in to a new column.  I have the graphical chart of the clustering. Needed to take out the total data set with updated new cluster column.

In K-Means, I could do that by running the below

```
iris_frame['NEW_COLUMN'] = pd.Series(y, index=iris_frame.index)
```

In Hierarchical clustering i could take out the desired outcome from the below formula

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
iris_CM=iris.copy()
iris_CM['Hierarchical']=fcluster(dist_comp,3, criterion='maxclust')
```

Anyone know how to do it with DBSCAN?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cluster labels by the `labels_` attribute. According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)

```py
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3],
              [8, 7], [8, 8], [25, 80]])
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2).fit(df)
df["clusters"] = clustering.labels_
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But  this case only reverts me a sample of numbers . these are the querries i ran...

Comment: what are the quieres you ran? this adds to every row of your training data the corresponding cluster

Comment: Thanks Paul,I have a file on this location "C:\Users\05807\Desktop\New folder (5)\FinalX.csv"

There are text columns. so the columns stated in the above report are,

"Sepal_length","Sepal_width","Petal_length","Petal_width" , "Species_name","Species_No","ID","K-Means","Hierarchical"

So i need to get a new column after "Hierarchical" column which is the clusters of DBSCAN. that means Cluster 1, cluster 2 o cluster 3.

This is total iris data set & added two more columns. There are 150 rows and i want to export all to a new file with that additional DBSCAN column. I am new to Python.

Comment: can you please send me the amended query you mentioned above after adding my path location of the file? Please? big help