# Annotating clustering from DBSCAN to original Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, sklearn-pandas, dbscan

I have working code that is utilizing dbscan to find tight groups of sparse spatial data imported with pd.read_csv.

I am maintaining the original spatial data locations and would like to annotate the labels returned by dbscan for each data point to the original dataframe and then write a csv with the same information.

So the code below is doing exactly what I would expect it to at this point, I would just like to extend it to import the label for each row in the original dataframe.

```
import argparse
import string
import os, subprocess
import pathlib
import glob
import gzip
import re
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

X = pd.read_csv(tmp_csv_name)
X = X.drop('Name', axis = 1)
X = X.drop('Type', axis = 1)
X = X.drop('SomeValue', axis = 1)
# only columns 'x' and 'y' now remain
db=DBSCAN(eps=EPS, min_samples=minSamples, metric='euclidean', algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30).fit(X)
labels = def_inst_dbsc.labels_
unique_labels = set(labels)
# maxX , maxY are manual inputs temporarily
while sizeX > 16 or sizeY > 16 :
    sizeX=sizeX*0.8 ; sizeY=sizeY*0.8
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(sizeX,sizeY))
plt.xlim(0,maxX)
plt.ylim(0,maxY)
plt.scatter(X['x'], X['y'], c=colors, marker="o", picker=True)
# hackX , hackY are manual inputs temporarily
# which represent the boundaries defined in the original dataset
poly = patches.Polygon(xy=list(zip(hackX,hackY)), fill=False)
ax.add_patch(poly)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Referring to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882879/dbscan-clustering-exporting-the-clustered-outcome-to-a-new-column-issue) 'code'(df = pd.DataFrame(Y);
df["Clusters"] = db.labels_) Where I copied "Y=X" before dropping columns, seems to be what I might want.

Comment: What still escapes me is how I might be able to use built-in min() and max() functions to extract a minimum containing rectangle for the locations for each of the labels >=0 (i.e., label 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. except label -1).